# Is there a way to increase armature performance on a high-poly character for sculpting?

Tags: armature, sculpting, shape-keys, performance

I am attempting to sculpt some corrective shape keys on my high-poly character, however the armature is seriously impacting my sculpting performance.  I have attempted to migrate my character to Zbrush to do my sculpting there, however all of my attempts to sculpt my shapes there have not managed to work.  Is there a way to improve the performance of the armature so I can create my corrective shapes?

Comment: Is there a reason why you try to rig the high-poly character and use corrective shapekeys on top of that? High-poly mesh + rig and high-poly mesh + shapekeys are both bad ideas because it results in very bad performance. The common workflow is to create a low-poly version, bake the normal map, rig the low-poly version and use corrective shapekeys for it if needed.